# How to initialize a object in a interface?

Tags: java, spring

I have this MovieService.java:

```
@Service
public class MovieService implements MovieInterface {
    
    @Autowired 
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @Autowired 
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    JwtUser user = (JwtUser)authentication.getPrincipal();
    User current_user = userRepository.findOne(user.getId());   

    @Override 
    public Movie createMovie(Movie movie) {

        current_user.addMovie(movie);
        userRepository.save(current_user);
    
        return movie;
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting when I'm compiling my code:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'movieController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'movieService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'movieService' defined in file [C:\Users\alucardu\Documents\projects\movieseat\backend\target\classes\com\movieseat\services\MovieService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.movieseat.services.MovieService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

This problem is resolved when I move the `authentication`, `user` and `current_user` properties into the `createMovie` method. But I want to use `current_user` in multiple methods so I would like to add it as a class member.

I also implement a MovieInterface:

```
package com.movieseat.interfaces;

// Java imports
import java.util.List;
import com.movieseat.model.security.User;
// Project imports
import com.movieseat.models.Movie;
import com.movieseat.security.JwtUser;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;

public interface MovieInterface {
    List<Movie> getAllmovies();
    Movie createMovie(Movie movie);
    void deleteMovie(Integer id);
}
```

So I thought maybe the code doesn't compile because the properties `authentication`, `user` and `current_user`aren't defined in the interface. Although I would expect a different error output for something like that. When I add the properties to the interface:

```
public interface MovieInterface {
    Authentication authentication;
    JwtUser user;
    User current_user;
    List<Movie> getAllmovies();
    Movie createMovie(Movie movie);
    void deleteMovie(Integer id);
}
```

I get the message:

> the blank final field authentication may not have been initialized
>
> the blank final field user may not have been initialized
>
> the blank final field current_user may not have been initialized

This message makes sense since the interface expects the fields to be final. And these fields have no value. So my question is, can I mark a field not final in a interface? And if I have to initialize a value for the fields what do I need to use?

I know you initialize a field `String name = "name";` But these properties are objects.

```
User current_user = {};
```

> Cannot convert from Object[] to User

Comment: you might rename your question to: how to access an auto wired attribute during initialization?

Comment: you cannot autowire the current user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service is a bean, and especially it is a singleton. That means there is only one instance of this service in your application.

But it may be called by different users. So you *have to* get the current user in your `createMovie` method (you already named it *current* User!).

When you try to initialize these fields in a PostConstruct method, you won't have a SecurityContext and you won't have a principal. And if you keep the info about the current user in the service instance, then all calls would be made on behalf of this one user, no matter where they come from.

So the best thing is to create a method :

```
private getUser() {
  Authentication authentication = 
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
  JwtUser user = (JwtUser)authentication.getPrincipal();
  User current_user = userRepository.findOne(user.getId());   
  return current_user;
}
```

and call that from within your different methods.

Comment: But then every time I call the `createMovie` method I have to call the `getUser` method that has to do some queries to get the current_user object. There's no way to create a field/member/property that holds the current_user information so I can call that value?

Comment: you have to get the current principal in _every_ call, that's right, because it might be a different one in every call. If you are using Spring security, you can add a `@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal` argument to your method call and Spring will inject the principal. But I'm not sure ifd this works for your context. But you could speedup the lookup from the repository by using a local cache (map user-id -> User), check especially https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link. Cleared some things up. I could move the getUser method to a userService so I don't have to put the getUser method in every class where I need the current_user.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is a bean. This means, all @Autowired fields will be set from someone else (Spring or CDI). Question is WHEN?. You might have bean A with auto wired bean B as property and the other way around. You need to wait, until all properties have been auto wired. You try to use userRepository during object creation. That's too early. Spring has to create the Java object (no way around this), but will do the autowiring after that. But with dependency injection, you will get told when all properties have been set, if you annotate a method with @PostConstruct.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    // it is safe now to use user repository, because it is not null anymore
}
```

Comment: this is right when talking about normal dependencies. But the problem here is to get the _current_ user that called the method and this can't be solved in a PostConstruct method

Comment: thanks - I agree, I didn't pay enough attention to Peter's use case, just to the NullPointerException. ;)